How I fix Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey
Here is my sample repo.
I use IntellJ IDEA, and run it on my android phone.
First time run is ok.
And Click run button again, it will show Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey in log.
How I fix it. thanks for your help.

part of error log, full log in my repo.'s readme

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while finalizing the widget tree:
Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.

The key [GlobalObjectKey int#371bd] was used by multiple widgets. The parents of those widgets were different widgets that both had the following description:
  IndexPage
A GlobalKey can only be specified on one widget at a time in the widget tree.
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3205:13)
#1      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
#2      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3149:20)
#3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
#4      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3144:36)
#5      BuildOwner._debugVerifyGlobalKeyReservation (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3213:6)
#6      BuildOwner.finalizeTree.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3267:11)
#7      BuildOwner.finalizeTree (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3342:8)
#8      WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1169:19)
#9      RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:468:5)
#10     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1397:15)
#11     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1318:9)
#12     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1040:9)
#13     PlatformDispatcher.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:837:16)
#17     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================




router code

final rootKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(debugLabel: "index");

@TypedShellRoute<IndexRoute>(
  routes: <TypedRoute<RouteData>>[
    TypedGoRoute<FirstRoute>(
      path: "/",
    ),
    TypedGoRoute<SecondRoute>(
      path: "/second",
    ),
  ],
)
class IndexRoute extends ShellRouteData {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> $navigatorKey = _shellKey;

  @override
  Widget builder(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state, Widget navigator) {
    return IndexPage(child: navigator);
  }
}

class FirstRoute extends GoRouteData {
  @override
  Page<void> buildPage(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const NoTransitionPage(child: FirstScreen());
  }
}

class SecondRoute extends GoRouteData {
  @override
  Page<void> buildPage(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const NoTransitionPage(child: SecondScreen());
  }
}


MainApp

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp.router(
      routerConfig: GoRouter(
        initialLocation: "/",
        routes: $appRoutes,
        navigatorKey: rootKey,
        redirect: (context, state) {
          return null;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}


env.

flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hant-TW)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/...
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (5 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/...
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/...
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /Users/...
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2024.1.6)
    • IntelliJ at /Users/mosil/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2024.1.6.app
    • Flutter plugin version 82.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 241.18968.26

[✓] Connected device
    • Pixel 4 (mobile)                • 98171FFAZ0038F            • android-arm64  • Android 13 (API 33)

I use IntellJ IDEA, and run it on my android phone.
First time run is ok.
And Click run button again, it will show Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey in log.

Please don't add tags to the title, and don't use [] brackets. They're used on this site to indicate closed or duplicate questions. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you start posting.

@pskink in my code, just final it's not a static GlobalKey, and i didn't assign to multiple widget.

I found what I need to modify
The two sub-widgets in ShellRoute, FirestRouteData and SecondRouteData should be included in IndexRouteData.
Therefore, in use, you should use build function directly instead of buildPage function, like:
class FirstRouteData extends GoRouteData {
  const FirstRouteData();

  // static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> $parentNavigatorKey = shellKey;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
    return const FirstScreen();
  }
}

The problem of Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey should be caused by buildPage. Let’s see if any friends online have clearer opinions.
